# vim incremental search stop at end of file

Tags: search, vim

In Vim, when I'm doing an incremental search for "x" by entering `/x` I then press `n` to jump to the next occurrence.  If I have just matched the last occurrence at the file, when I press `n` the cursor will start to look for a match at the beginning of the file---it will loop back to the beginning.  **I do not want it to loop back to the beginning.**  I want `n` to simply not find any more matches after it reaches the final occurrence.  The reason I want this behavior is so that I can easily see when I have searched through the entire file.

Does anyone know how to effect this behavior?

FYI: I am using the following .vimrc options:

```
colorscheme zenburn   " zenburn colorscheme

set nocompatible      " prevent Vim from emulating Vi's bugs
set scrolloff=5       " keeps cursor away from top/bottom of screen
set nobackup          " don't make automatic backups

set incsearch         " incremental searching
set ignorecase        " case insensitive matching
set smartcase         " smart case matching
set showmatch         " show matching bracket

set autoindent        " indentation
set smartindent       " indentation
set cindent           " indenting for C code
set tabstop=4         " 4-space tabs
set shiftwidth=4      " 4-space tabs

syntax on             " syntax highlighting
filetype on           " behavior based on file type
filetype plugin on    " behavior based on file type
filetype indent on    " behavior based on file type

set visualbell        " replace beeping with flashing screen

set gfn=Lucida_Sans_Typewriter:h10:cANSI
```

Comment: For lurkers, questions like these are welcome on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Turn off the `'wrapscan'` option.

```
set nowrapscan
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something direct and simple :)

Comment: I have just added this line to my `~/.vimrc`. When I'll need to wrap I'll do a `:1`

Answer (score 0):

For `init.lua`:

```
vim.opt.wrapscan = false
```