# How to delete everything until the next pattern match **or** *the end of the file* in vim

Tags: vim

Can I get vim to delete everything until the next pattern match **or** *the end of the file*?

I thought about *searching* for a pattern **or** the end of the file (at the same time), still allowing wraparound (so not just [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854471/vim-incremental-search-stop-at-end-of-file)), which would then allow me to <kbd>dn</kbd> to delete until the next match (which would then include the end of the file), but I couldn't figure out how to encode `|EOF` in the search.

Perhaps it's possible to add something to this one instance of the delete command (e.g. `d/Gn`, which is not afaik a thing) or something? Something *like* enabling `nowrapscan` just for this one command...

Use Case: When editing `--verbose` git commit messages, where the diff is included in the commit message template, I like to add a comment to the message about a section of the diff, delete that code section, and repeat until all the code diffs are gone. I search for `^\(@@\|diff\|$\)`, which finds the beginnings of a new file (`^diff`) or hunk (`^@@`) or blank line (`^$`), and then can use <kbd>dn</kbd> to delete down to the next match, which works fine until the last hunk (which may extend past the end of the screen) - if I accidentally do this there, it wraps around and deletes *upward*. Easy enough to undo and <kbd>dG</kbd>, but still kind of annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\%$` pattern, that matches the end of the file.

So `d/x\|\%$` to delete up to the first `x` or the end of the file.

Comment: Close enough - `dn` with this in the search deletes all but the last character, but I can just ignore the last character ;) THANKS!