# How to search only until end of document / be warned at end of document? (LibreOffice)

Tags: search, eof, libreoffice

Using LibreOffice Writer (version 6.0.7.3), I'm often searching for strings from within largish Writer document, and am using the ctrl+F search. While searching, I'm rather concentrated on looking at where the searched term is found from within the document text, and just press the arrow at the toolbar using mouse to get me to the next instance of the search string. I do this without actually looking at the toolbar.

When I've found the last search string from within the document, LibreOffice Writer only prints darker grey text "Reached end of document" on lighter grey background (sort of "grayed out" thing) on the toolbar. But -- me having eyes fixed on the document text and not looking at the toolbar -- I just keep on pressing the arrow button, and after second or third round get a sort of Déjà-vu feeling. Looking *then* at the toolbar, while not actually at the last specimen of the searched string within the document there seems to be no indication that I'm half way on my third helping...

What is the advantage of ***not*** actually allowing me (while using ctrl+F or ctrl+H at tools->options... or whatnot) to select that *to me* next should not go past the end of the document (by "next" momentarily becoming "first") without me being properly warned with a "yes-no-whatnot" dialog box that really would stop me from going past end, and be asked if I really want to go for a second helping?

Or have I really (again) missed something?

On my PC (Xbuntu 18.04.4 LTS , Xfce desktop environment 4.12, 32-bit) the same nastiness is found at all possible text editors:

- Leafpad, version 0.8.18.1
- Mousepad, version 0.4.0
- Notepadqq, version v1.4.2
- Gedit, version 3.28.1
- Thunderbird, version 68.7.0
- Firefox 75.0
- LibreOffice Writer, Version: 6.0.7.3

The only one that seems to have it the way I wish is:

- Notepad++, version 7.5.1 (under Wine), it has a checkbox: "wrap around"

Am I just having too narrow line of vision, or is this what *everybody* (except me) really only wants...

pekka

PS: I have asked the same question at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/234758/ with no success...

Answer (score 0):

Once again, [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) saves the day.

[image: Continue searching from start?]

My preferred text editor also has an option: [vim incremental search stop at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854471/vim-incremental-search-stop-at-end-of-file)

Comment: This won't help me with Leafpad, Mousepad, Notepadqq, Gedit, Thunderbird, Firefox....

Is it really so, that everyone except me likes the "search" to continue from the top and after second or third round get this deja-vue feeling that I've been here before...